# Android uncaught exception logs

Tags: java, android, exception, proguard

I've written a piece of code that logs all uncaught exceptions that may arise in my android application. Now then since I have encrypted my apk, all the exception logs don't have the exact class names and instead the logs refer to classes such as a.java or b.java etc. Any ideas how I could preserve the logs so that I can track any exceptions that can arise?

Comment: Check : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Answer (score 1):

Add `-dontobfuscate` to your proguard config file.